# Twilio - Carrier Lookup

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

How do I access the phone carrier with Twilio's carrier lookup?

Here is some of my sample code:

```
require_once('twilio/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "--------------";
$token = "------------------";
$client = new Lookups_Services_Twilio($sid, $token);



$number = $client->phone_numbers->get("5555555555", array("CountryCode" => "US", "Type" => "carrier"));

//How do I access the carrier here?
    echo $number->phone_number;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you call for the carrier details, they are all returned as an object on the number called `carrier`. You can see this in the example response on the [Twilio Lookup](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) page. So, with your code:

```
$number = $client->phone_numbers->get("5555555555", array("CountryCode" => "US", "Type" => "carrier"));

echo $number->carrier->name;
echo $number->carrier->type;
```

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thank you. Is there a list of all possible carrier names that twilio can possibly lookup?

Answer (score 2):

With Twilio 5.x SDK, things changed very slightly:

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client as Twilio;

$client = new Twilio("sid", "token");
$response = $client->lookups->phoneNumbers("+15551234567")->fetch(["type" => "carrier"]);
echo $response->carrier["type"] . "\r\n";
echo $response->carrier["name"];
```

See https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups for the complete current documentation.

Comment: When did 5.x come out? I haven't gotten any information that it updated in the past couple of months.

Comment: 5.0.0 was released in August 2016 (https://packagist.org/packages/twilio/sdk#5.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

When fetching "type" => "caller-name", the response can be unwound with:

```
echo $response->callerName["caller_name"];
```

camelCase, hyphen and dash all in one use case!